# HTTPS Server CORS Issue

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a NodeJS Express server which I am switching over from http to https. I have two files starting this:

app.js which defines the express part of the server, sets headers etc...

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const dataRoutes = require('./routes/data');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //"https://www.wordleleague.org");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
})

app.use("/api/data", dataRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

and server js which is the main part of the code, the launched file:

```
const app = require("./app");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);
server.listen(port);
```

Whilst this all worked fine when I was using http, now I get a CORS error when trying to query this:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://localhost:3000/api/data/login. (Reason:
> CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 499.

It looks like the express app object isnt being used by the createServer. This all worked in http but its when I tried adding the credentials to the object for https that it went wrong.

If there is any further info anybody needs I am happy to provide, but this seems like all that is relevant. The requests are not being routed to the appropriate method and the http call from the angular app is definatele working.

**Edit - The call to the server and more error detail**

This is the code which calls the server:

```
this.subscriptions['leaguesub'] = this.http.get<{success: boolean, data: League[]}>(environment.apiUrl+'api/data/all/userId=' + id).subscribe({
    next: (result: {success: boolean, data: League[]}) => {
        this.leaguesLocal = [...result.data];
        this.leagues.next([...this.leaguesLocal]); 
 }})
```

Works fine when I am using http. The only header which is added is an authorisation token:

```
req.headers.set('Authorization', "Bearer " + token)
```

The error it seems is a 499:

> Status 499 Request has been forbidden by antivirus Referrer Policy
> strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**edit 2**

If I reverse the order of createserver arguments then the CORs issue goes away but I have a new, different CORs issue:

```
const server = https.createServer(app, httpsOptions);
```

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://localhost:3001/api/user/login. (Reason:
> CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

One of the comments suggests using a CORs module but im not sure why my code isnt working

**edit 3**

Ok so I modified the main app.js express file to reflect the CORS suggestion made below:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

And the error is persistent. Still no luck connecting to the server or any idea how to debug it. I tried using these methods to check a connection:

```
app.post("*", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`post here`);
    next();
})

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`get here`);
    next();
})
```

But alas I get no info from the concole about these running the event of a call being made to the API. Same errors as before.

**edit 4**

Running in Chrome gives me a new info source:

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

Looking this up it seems there may be a problem with the SSL certificate. It is a self created SSL certificate which normally requires you to press ALLOW or something. It would explain why there seems to be nothing getting through to the server whatsoever as my browser is blocking it.

The problem then it how to get around this?

Comment: What is the specific request (the exact URL, content-type, custom headers, etc...) and where that request comes from that causes this CORS issue?  If the request comes from JS code, please show the code that generates the request.

Comment: Just use the pre-built [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware, otherwise you're just implementing semi-complete CORS functionality

Comment: When you make a CORs request, there are [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) that do not trigger pre-flight and there are [non-simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) that do trigger pre-flight and require your server to response to an OPTIONS request before the actual request comes through.

Comment: Added the code which calls the api, more error detail and the cusom auth header sent with it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I ensured that the endpoint I was making this request to was an http endpoint. This was okay because this URL was only for development. When I deployed, the endpoint URL would change to the https.

To re-iterate, Kaspersky let it go through once the endpoint was changed from "https://localhost:3001/login/password" to "http://localhost:3002/login/password".